# How to create Visual Studio (.sln) file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-foxpro, sln-file

I am currently working on a project which is basically conversion of VisualFoxPro projects to ASP MVC project dynamically

I have created all folders,controllers,views files in my code on a button click by simply creating a file with that particular extension and giving path to it

In the same way i created (.sln) file but it is not running when i generate my project on button click

All the files of a blank MVC project is created in this way

```
      File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(ModelsFolder, "AccountViewModels.cs"), "here i put the code which is in the default files");
```

now i am facing problem in creating .sln file , should i use SLNTools to create .sln file or is there any other way of doing it

i forgot to mention that there is some file reading of foxpro projects so after reading files i am creating like a view and a controller for a single form,menu dynamically and i dont think so using SDK i am able to do that if yes then any help would be appreciated

Comment: So basically, you wrote a program that changes the files extension?

Comment: i wrote a program to generate visual studio ASP MVC files of a blank project and now i need to run it with solution files

Comment: i am trying to add reference of slntool but there is no such references present

Comment: You don't need .sln file for running application. .proj file will be enough

Comment: "which is basically conversion of VisualFoxPro projects to ASP MVC project"     Are you trying to create a Web version of a VFP Application?   If so, you are going about it all wrong.  Instead of asking how to use a certain tool in hopes that it will work for you - it is more effective to ask how to approach your goal.

Comment: if you can help me to the right path the ill be really thankful to you

Answer (score -1):

Do the below following steps.

File -> New -> Project -> Templates -> Other Project Types select the visual studio solutions.

Comment: Sir problem is that i am creating a blank mvc project on a button click in my desktop application 
for this i am creating all the default files which is in blank mvc project 
on button click project is creating but iam unable to run it 
is there a simple solution to do this 
ps i have to read foxpro files and create controllers and views after mapping

Comment: don't understand bro what do you want.